# Is there a way to use narrator voices in the Text-To-Speech voices

Tags: windows-11, text-to-speech, text-to-speech-voices

Given:
Windows 11 Pro

Is there a way to use the Natural voices in Narrator to TTS (Text-To-Speech)?

[image]

Comment: microphone settings is not part of text-to-speech